# Not able to use Try Except block in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox

I am trying to extract the urls of the main images of Amazon.com from an internal site, but for certain ASINs, the website returns an empty table without any url, and I want to add the try and except block to pass the same, but I am not at all able to do it.

And also, while running the below code, I am getting multiple windows. So for each row I am getting a new Firefox window open with the website, how can I get a single window open and run all the ASINs in it ?

**Output Table that I am getting is:**

| asin | image_urls |
| --- | --- |
| B094WD6PGC | [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51zzR4ncthL.\_SY250.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51zzR4ncthL.%5C_SY250.jpg) |
| B082XJRGDX | [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51v0SdaC28L.\_SY250.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51v0SdaC28L.%5C_SY250.jpg) |

Attaching the screenshot of the website when it returns empty result (if the ASIN is no more active)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUWYw.png)

I am kind of new to python, and I have tried almost every possible way with my limited knowledge, but not able to get this thing fixed, can I please get some help.

Thank you in Advance :)

```
import requests as r
import urllib
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


def extract_imgs(asin):
    
    # Initiating the Firefox browser
    browser = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    browser.add_argument('--headless')
    browser.binary_location = r'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path ='C:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe')

    # Loading the main site to access the local storage
    driver.get('internal_website')

    # Waiting up to 1 minute for manual Midway authentication
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(lambda d: d.current_url.startswith('internal_website'))
    driver.execute_script('localStorage.setItem("mpName", "us")')
    url = "internal_website" + str(asin) + "&region=us"
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Waiting upto 10 seconds to load the images
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(10)

    # Extracting the main image url with the xpath
    img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/img")
    return img.get_attribute('src')
    
    

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\" + os.getlogin() + "\\Desktop\\" + "asins.xlsx")

df['image_urls'] = df['asin'].apply(extract_imgs)

df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\" + os.getlogin() + "\\Desktop\\" + "image_load.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: This question is not relevant to the tag AWS.

Comment: Tag removed, @Captain Caveman.